# Will using Javascript sorcery have a negative effect on the game?

Tags: cheats, candy-box

I uh.. have been using [Javascript sorcery](https://www.google.com/search?q=candy+box+~cheats)* to get ridiculous amount of candies in Candy Box.

[image: Javascript sorcery]

I am wondering if I could break the game, encounter horrible game bugs or by-design game features that could have a negative effect on gameplay if I keep on doing this. Can I add any amount of candy or lollipops that I want without encountering any problems?

---

<sup>* cheats</sup>

Comment: Related: [How do I enter cheats using the Javascript / Developer console?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116376/4797)

Answer (score 10):

I found a possible side effect. If you eat a ridiculous amount of candies, your hitpoints will get so high, that...

> ...[fighting yourself](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116151/4797) will take a *long* time:   [image]

Comment: Since we're using javascript cheats anyhow, this can easily be overcome by writing in the code sword.setSpecialPower(x);.

Answer (score 4):

## No

I needed to sleep, so set `candies.candiesPerSecond` very *very* high so I could complete the game and get to bed.

[image]

There are no negative side effects, I was even able to save and reload the game.

Answer (score 2):

Since javascript has dynamic variables, you can make the numbers as high as you possibly want as long as javascript can handle it. For AFAIK there shouldn't be a problem with huge numbers. It will be transformed to the e-notation. Once you finish the game and randomize everything using the "computer" it also comes up with such huge values.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, whenever I had cheated, I couldn't move up and down in hell. I don't know what's wrong or how to fix it. It's probably because I'm using Chrome.

@badp I wish I could do that. I honestly have no idea why my game is doing this. It's annoying, but I guess I'm just going to have to do this the hard way :P.

@Ullallulloo Thanks for editing and respecting my answer :).

Comment: I cheated rather blatantly and haven't had trouble.

Comment: What Javascript codes were you using?

Answer (score 0):

The only negative aspect I can see, is messing up a spelling, that messes up your game in some unforeseen manner. Nearly impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Typing `candies.nbrOwned = 100000`
in Console after inspecting has worked for me to get a lot of candies.