# What does the sorceress mean by being "able to surpass yourself"?

Tags: candy-box

The sorceress recently gave me an option to buy the ability to "*surpass myself*" in exchange for a million lollipops. I bought that ability. Afterwards, the sorceress now says this:

[image: Sorceress: You are now able to surpass yourself. Congratulations !]
<sup>You are now able to surpass yourself. Congratulations !</sup>

- What triggers the sorceress into selling you the ability to surpass
  yourself?
- **And what does it mean if I am now "able to surpass myself"?**
- **What changes do the "ability to surpass yourself" do?**

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I asked this question before that. I am asking about the details of what "being able to surpass myself" does, and edited this question to further differentiate it. This question also currently does not have an answer in that other question of mine, as this was not asked about in that question.

Comment: Close/leave closed voters: Mind explaining why this question is a duplicate of the other one? The things asked about here are not asked there, and this question doesn't have an answer there. "*If the question looks the same, but the answers aren't solving the asker's problem, that is not a dupe – that is a legitimate new question.*" - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux

Comment: Question delete voter(s): From http://gaming.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools: "*be cautious when deleting questions closed as duplicates; [they can serve as a signpost](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions/), directing users to useful answers on another question.*"

Comment: I really don't feel like this is the same question as the linked 'duplicate'.  Did you guys even read them before voting to close?

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously a spoiler; don't read on if you don't want a spoiler

> Eventually you will find a quest called Yourself; in it, you literally fight yourself. Everything you do is mirrored, buffs and whatnot too, so it is impossible to win. The Surpass Yourself increases the damage done to the You (Clone) while not damaging You (Player), making the level completable.

Comment: What changes, exactly, when one buys the "ability to surpass yourself"? How does it make one's original self better than the other "self" (the clone), enabling the original self to beat the other "self"?

Comment: `Everything you do is mirrored, buffs and whatnot too, so it is impossible to win.`   Tell that to *Zelda 2* and *Prince of Persia*. `;-)`