# How do I lower my hitpoints?

Tags: cheats, candy-box

I ate too much candy, and increased my max health too much that I now [find it very difficult to defeat myself.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116155/4797)

[Since my clone has the exact same hitpoints as me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/116200/4797), is there a way to make that fight easier and faster? **Is there a way to lower my hitpoints?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reset your effective health points by resetting the amount of candies you've eaten.

In the developer's console, enter the following command:

```
candies.setNbrEaten(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually lower not-yourself's hitpoints:

```
quest.things[1].hp = 1
```

...but I found that it doesn't work. It seems like the other yourself is hardcoded to have your number of hitpoints minus 3 (well, 3 was the HP delta for me), so this wasn't useful.

What *did* work for me, then, was lowering *my own* hitpoints:

```
quest.things[0].hp = 5
```

(I'm not actually positive that such a change will let you win every time; sounds more like a coin throw on paper to me. Should you fail to beat yourself, you can try again immediately with `quest.tiredTime = 1`.)

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to lower your hitpoints, but you should instead save up 1,000,000 lollipops and buy the "surpass yourself" spell from the witch and you will win everytime.

Comment: [See here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/116155/4797), to know why I would like to lower my hitpoints.